# MySQL - CONCAT two fields and use them in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, string-concatenation

As the title suggests, I was wondering how to `concat` two fields in a `where clause` in `mysql`. This is an example of what I'm trying to achieve :

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name) AS name FROM `users`
WHERE name LIKE "%John Doe%"
```

The point is that `first_name` and `last_name` are separate fields, and I want to enable my `PHP` application to search for a full person's name.

Any tips?

Cheers!

Comment: Concat with `%` before and after ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this ::

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name) AS name FROM `users`
WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name) LIKE "%John Doe%"
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I was actually expecting some way to use the aliased field in `where clause`, don't know if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

pick up the users as view then query outside select query

```
select name from (select first_name||last_name FROM `users`
    WHERE frst_name LIKE "%John%" or last name like "%doe%") where name like '%John Doe%'
```